# How to programmatically place a label inside a grid within another grid?

Tags: c#, xaml, grid

Take for example this xaml code:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <Grid Grid.Column="1">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition/>
               <ColumnDefinition/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Grid Grid.Column="1">
               <Label Content="Label"/>
          </Grid>
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```

How would one go about creating this form structure in c# code? The thing that is throwing me off is the grid with two columns within the parent grid's right column.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Grid grid1 = new Grid();
    grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

    Content = grid1;

    Grid grid2 = new Grid();
    grid2.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
    grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

    grid1.Children.Add(grid2);

    Label label = new Label {Content = "Label"};
    label.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);

    grid2.Children.Add(label);
}
```